# Value-initializing an automatic object?

Tags: c++, initialization

I'm writing a template class and at one point in my code would like to be able to value-initialize an object of the parameterized type on the stack.  Right now, I'm accomplishing this by writing something to this effect:

```
template <typename T> void MyClass<T>::doSomething() {
    T valueInitialized = T();
    /* ... */
}
```

This code works, but (unless the compiler is smart) it requires an unnecessary creation and destruction of the temporary `T` object.  What I'd like to write is the following, which I know is incorrect:

```
template <typename T> void MyClass<T>::doSomething() {
    T valueInitialized(); // WRONG: This is a prototype!
    /* ... */
}
```

My question is whether there is a nice way to value-initialize the automatic object without having to explicitly construct a temporary object and assign it over to the automatic object.  Can this be done?  Or is `T var = T();` as good as it gets?

Comment: Good question. :) (Though you should know better than to thank in a question body!)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is this a concern?  If `T` is a user-defined type, it should have a default constructor.  If it's an intrinsic type, the performance loss from copy-constructing should be negligible.  Even that's assuming that the compiler won't optimize it away.

Comment: @Maxpm- This is mostly out of curiosity.  I've always used the `T var = T();` syntax and figured that there was probably a cleaner way to do it.  You're completely correct that the performance hit should be negligible.

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671532/non-copyable-objects-and-value-initialization-g-vs-msvc

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The following uses *copy-initialization*, which is 'probably fine' 95% of the time in C++03:

```
T var = T();
```

But for *generic* (C++03) code, you should always prefer *direct-initialization* to account for that other 5%:

```
T var((T())); // extra parentheses avoid the most vexing parse – the extra parentheses
              // force the contents to be evaluated as an expression, thus implicitly
              // *not* as a declaration.
```

Or better yet, use the [Boost](http://www.boost.org/).[Utility.ValueInit](http://www.boost.org/libs/utility/value_init.htm) library, which packages up the ideal behavior for you along with workarounds for various compiler deficiencies (sadly, more than one might think):

```
boost::value_initialized<T> var;
```

---

For C++11, one can use list-initialization syntax to achieve direct value-initialization in a significantly less noisy/ugly manner:

```
T var{}; // unambiguously value-initialization†
```

(<sup>†</sup>N.b. technically this will invoke `std::initializer_list<>` constructors instead of performing value-initialization for certain pathological types. Presumably the net result should be the same.)

Comment: Ugh, that looks like LISP. `:)` Does this really work with all types? `+1` from me for suggesting a boost library.

Comment: Yes, it works with all types. The parentheses are benign but disambiguate the declaration.

Comment: Unless I'm misinterpreting the difference between direct- and copy-initialization, this only makes a difference in whether conversion constructors are permitted, not in whether a temporary object is created.  Is this correct?  If so, what advantage does this particular approach offer over the copy-initialized version?

Comment: @templatetypedef : According to the standard there's no advantage either way in this context/usage, but some older compilers elide the copy in the case of direct-initialization and not in the case of copy-initialization (MSVC and Borland especially come to mind, but I seem to recall GCC prior to 3.4 being similarly affected). I.e., if your code is only going to be built with recent compilers it's inconsequential -- hence "*which is probably fine 99% of the time*."

Comment: This doesn't work with all types after all.  Specifically, it doesn't work with non-copyable/non-moveable types.  Happily, the Boost library does.

Comment: I didn't know the Most Vexing Parse surrendered if you threw enough parentheses at it.

Comment: @Quentin : Indeed, the extra parentheses force the contents to be evaluated as an expression, thus implicitly _not_ as a declaration. This behavior has noticeable effects in other contexts, such as with `return` expressions (NRVO cannot apply, move is no longer implicit, etc.) and `decltype` semantics.

Answer (score 16):

You can use curly braces in C++0x:

```
T valueInitialized{};
```

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought of C++11! `+1` from me!

Answer (score 5):

No, there isn't any other way to reliably value-initialize a template type in C++03.

If you can count on `T` only being class types with default constructors, you could just write

```
T valueInitialized;
```

but if `T` might as well be a built-in type,

```
T valueInitialized = T();
```

is the way to go.

Do you have any reason to not to trust your compiler to optimize away that copy?

Comment: Oh, I absolutely trust the compiler to do it. :-)  This is mostly a question about whether there's a more elegant way to do this that doesn't rely on a smart compiler author.