# C++ default initialization and value initialization: which is which, which is called when and how to reliably initialize a template-type member

Tags: c++, initialization, default-value

My question somewhat overlaps with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803153/what-are-primitive-types-default-initialized-to-in-c) and several other similar ones. Those have some great answers, but I've read them and I'm still confused, so please don't consider this question a duplicate.

So, I have the following code:

```
class A {
    public: int _a;
}

void main()
{
    A inst1;
    A* inst2 = new A;
    A* inst3 = new A();
}
```

`_a` is left uninitialized in `inst1` and `inst2` and is initialized to `0` in `inst3`.
Which initialization is called which, and why does the code work as it does? Please take into account I don't have a C++ 03 standard at hand, but I have the last C++ 11 draft (I'm programming by '03 standard, though), so quotations of the '03 standard or references to '11 are most welcome.

P. S. The original task behind this research was to correctly zero-initialize a member of arbitrary template type `T`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Value-initializing an automatic object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298001/value-initializing-an-automatic-object)

Comment: for upcoming users check this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032638/default-variable-value

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Not so hard:

```
A x;
A * p = new A;
```

These two are *default initialization*. Since you don't have a user-defined constructor, this just means that all members are default-initialized. Default-initializing a fundamental type like `int` means "no initialization".

Next:

```
A * p = new A();
```

This is *value initialization*. (I don't think there exists an automatic version of this in C++98/03, though in C++11 you can say `A x{};`, and this *brace-initialization* becomes value-initialization. Moreover, `A x = A();` is close enough practically despite being *copy-initialization*, or `A x((A()))` despite being *direct-initialization*.)

Again, in your case this just means that all members are value-initialized. Value initialization for fundamental types means *zero-initialization*, which in turn means that the variables are initialized to zero (which all fundamental types have).

For objects of class type, both default- and value-initialization invoke the default constructor. What happens then depends on whether default constructor is compiler or user defined. If user defined, in both default- and value-initialization behave the same way and what happens depends on the constructor's initializer list, and the game continues recursively for member variables. If compiler defined, default and value initialization behave as expected.

Comment: I understand how it works for classes (they have constructors, either explicitly defined or default). Only built-in type objects got me confused. Thanks for the explanation. However, I didn't get the comment about copy-initialization and direct initialization. Haven't you mixed them up?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: I hope not. Don't confuse "initialization", which is a grammatical concept, with "construction", which is part of the object model. The former sometimes causes the latter, but there's some overlapping and confusing terminology at work.

Comment: Should `A x = A((A()))` be `A x( A() );` instead?

Comment: @K-ballo: Most certainly no. Please try it for yourself and weep :-)

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Maybe `A x( (A()) );` then? Otherwise is still *copy-initialization* isn't it?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: OK, now I'm totally lost, I fail to see how a spare pare of parentheses make any difference. Oh, and I got the copy-initialization, scratch my previous question. I must admit, I didn't notice the `=`, which invokes a copy constructor.

Comment: @K-ballo: Ah, now we're getting somewhere. Thanks, that was indeed wrong! Fixed...

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: I had a mistake, as K-Ballo pointed out. It should be: `A x((A()));`. That's direct-initialization, but it essentially boils down to value-initialization. You cannot omit the extra parentheses because of the C++ parsing rules.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: Not at all :-) It's copy-initialization because it involves the equals-sign ("`=`"). Copy-initialization can result in any number of things, depending on what it is you're initializing. Like `int x = 5;`, which would result in the same code as direct-initialization `int x(5);`. On the other hand, `Foo x = 6;` would cause the constructor `Foo(6)` to be called, and `Foo x = Foo(6);` would almost certainly, too (though in GCC you can suppress this via `-fno-elide-constructors`).

Comment: But that's an optimization, isn't it? Shouldn't the plain naive approach involve copy constructor?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: I guess, but the standard does permit the elision of copy construction, even if the copy constructor has side effects. That's why I say "practically close enough". You have a similar issue with aggregates: `Foo x[] = { 1, 2, 3 };` vs. `Foo x[] = { Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3) };`

Comment: OK, I've run some tests. Now, could you please explain why exactly does `A x ( (A()))` call a constructor `A::A()`, and `A x ( A() )` doesn't?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: Because `A x(A())` declares `x` as a function returning `A` and taking one argument which itself is a (pointer to a) function returning `A` and taking no arguments. It's not what you were thinking you were declaring :-)

Comment: Got it, but how does another pair of braces change things? I thought nested adjacent braces are transparent (have no effect).

Comment: Suppose if I have a class member `_x` of type `T`, and I write initializer list as follows: `_x ( T () ). If my understanding is correct, this is a direct initialization with a value-initialized object, so in the end _x will be 0 if `T` is of built-in type. Is that right?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: initializer lists are a different context. The C++ grammar has a few curious corner situations like that... in response to your previous question: parentheses mustn't surround type declarations, so `(A())` is parsed as an *expression* and all is well.

Comment: @KerrekSB if object is static or globally declared then it is value initialized right ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `A inst4 ();` is treated as a function declaration.  `std::string str();` should be the same (i.e. I think you mistakenly thought it worked).

Apparently (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613341/what-do-the-following-phrases-mean-in-c-zero-default-and-value-initializat)), C++03 will have `inst3._a` be 0, but C++98 would have left it uninitialized.

Comment: You're right, they're both function declaration, I didn't notice a warning. I thought it should be an error.