# Default initialization of POD vs. non-POD class types

Tags: c++, initialization, c++03

The C++ standard says (8.5/5):

> To default-initialize an object of type `T` means:
>
> - If `T` is a non-POD class type (clause 9), the default constructor for `T` is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if `T` has no
>     accessible default constructor).
> - If `T` is an array type, each element is default-initialized.
> - Otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

With this code

```
struct Int { int i; };

int main()
{
    Int a;
}
```

the object `a` is default-initialized, but clearly `a.i` is not necessarily equal to 0 . Doesn't that contradict the standard, as `Int` is POD and is not an array ?

**Edit**  Changed from `class` to `struct` so that `Int` is a POD.

Comment: "clearly a.i is not necessarily equal to 0" why? "Otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.".

Comment: You are reading an outdated spec. in the most recent spec, default initialization will leave you values uninitialized

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Could you show the updated text on this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From 8.5.9 of the 2003 standard:

> If no initializer is specified for an object, and the object is of
>   (possibly cv-qualified) non-POD class type (or array thereof), the
>   object shall be default-initialized; if the object is of
>   const-qualified type, the underlying class type shall have a
>   user-declared default constructor. **Otherwise, if no initializer is
>   specified for a nonstatic object, the object and its subobjects, if
>   any, have an indeterminate initial value**); if the object or any of
>   its subobjects are of const-qualified type, the program is ill-formed.

The class you show is a POD, so the highlighted part applies, and your object will not be initialized at all (so section 8.5/5, which you quote, does not apply at all).

**Edit:** As per your comment, here the quote from section 8.5/5 of the final working draft of the current standard (I don't have the real standard, but the FDIS is supposedly very close):

> To default-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> — if T is a (possibly
>   cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9), the default constructor for T is
>   called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible
>   default constructor);
>
> — if T is an array type, each element is
>   default-initialized;
>
> — **otherwise, no initialization is performed.**

Comment: According to the standard, all non-static data members of a POD must have the same access control; it does not need to be `public`.

Comment: @Gorpik: Maybe that changed in C++11, but in C++03 a POD is an aggregate, and an aggregate must not have any private or protected non-static data-members (8.5.1.1).

Comment: @Björn I don't have a standard with me. The part I reproduced in my question was obtained from other questions in SO. How does your answer ties back to the part of the standard I've shown above ?

Comment: @user1042389: The part you quote would only apply if you were using default-initialization. The section I quoted specifies that the example you show does not perform any initialization, hence the section you quoted does not apply.

Comment: @Björn According to http://stackoverflow.com/q/1613383/1042389 my example is a default-initialization. What else could it be ?

Comment: @user1042389: The section quoted in that answer defines what happens if an object is initialized using one of these three methods. The section I quote defines that in your example *none of these methods applies*. Your example has no initialization at all.

Comment: @Björn Could you give an example as how a POD is default-initialized ?

Comment: @user1042389: Thomas Maierhofer gives such an example in his answer.

Comment: @Björn This answer (http://stackoverflow.com/q/8106064/1042389) says exactly the contrary of what you're saying, i.e., the referred answer says explicitly that `Int a;` default-initializes `a`. Also regarding Thomas answer, how could `Int a = Int();` be considered a default-initialization ? `Int()` value-initializes a temporary with 0, which is then copied into `a`.

Comment: @user that's because the referred answer uses the current C++ rules and this answer explicitly mentions that it uses the outdated C++ rules.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb As I said above, I don't have the standard with me. The part I reproduced in my question was obtained from another question in SO. Could you show me, as an answer, the updated quote on this matter.

Comment: @user1042389: I added a quote from the current standard.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable is not initialized. 
Use

```
Int a = Int();
```

to initialize your POD or declare a standard constructor to make it non POD;
But you can also use your POD uninitialized for performance reasons like:

```
Int a;
a.i = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the object `a` is not default-initialized. If you want to default-initialize it, you have to say:

```
Int a = Int() ;
```

Comment: Oh yes, it is default-initialized. `Int a;` asks for `a` to be constructed using the default constructor. `Int a = Int();` asks for a temporary `Int` object to be constructed using the default constructor, and then copy construct `a` using this temporary, though the compiler can (and most probably will) skip the copy constructor and default construct `a` directly.

Comment: @TonyK @Thomas In any case, how could `Int a = Int();` be considered a default-initialization ? `Int()` value-initializes a temporary with 0, which is then copied into a.