# c++ placement new in a home made vector container

Tags: c++, placement-new

There are some questions quite similar around here, but they couldn't help me get my mind around it.
Also, I'm giving a full example code, so it might be easier for others to understand.

I have made a vector container (couldn't use stl for memory reasons) that used to use only operator= for push_back*, and once I came accross placement new, I decided to introduce an additional "emplace_back" to it**.

*(T::operator= is expected to deal with memory management)

**(the name is taken from a similar function in std::vector that I've encountered later, the original name I gave it was a mess).

I read some stuff about the danger of using placement new over operator new[] but couldn't figure out if the following is ok or not, and if not, what's wrong with it, and what should I replace it with, so I'd appreciate your help.

This is of couse a simplified code, with no iterators, and no extended functionality, but it makes the point :

```
template <class T>
class myVector {
public :
    myVector(int capacity_) {
        _capacity = capacity_;
        _data = new T[_capacity];
        _size = 0;
    }

    ~myVector() {
        delete[] _data;
    }

    bool push_back(T const & t) {
        if (_size >= _capacity) { return false; }
        _data[_size++] = t;
        return true;
    }

    template <class... Args>
    bool emplace_back(Args const & ... args) {
        if (_size >= _capacity) { return false; }
        _data[_size].~T();
        new (&_data[_size++]) T(args...);
        return true;
    }

    T * erase (T * p) {
        //assert(/*p is not aligned*/);
        if (p < begin() || p >= end()) { return end(); }
        if (p == &back()) { --_size; return end(); }
        *p = back();
        --_size;
        return p;
    }

    // The usual stuff (and more)
    int capacity()          { return _capacity;             }
    int size()              { return _size;                 }
    T * begin()             { return _data;                 }
    T * end()               { return _data + _size;         }
    T const * begin() const { return _data;                 }
    T const * end()   const { return _data + _size;         }
    T & front()             { return *begin();              }
    T & back()              { return *(end() - 1);          }
    T const & front() const { return *begin();              }
    T const & back() const  { return *(end() - 1);          }
    T & operator[] (int i)  { return _data[i];              }
    T const & operator[] (int i) const { return _data[i];   }
private:
    T * _data;
    int _capacity;
    int _size;
};
```

Thanks

Comment: You'll be calling the destructor of an uninitialised T at least

Comment: Why? (or.. where?) all elements are initialized with empty constructor (T::T()) when using new[] inside myVector::myVector(int) (only) constructor...

Comment: Calling `new T[ n ];` does not construct the elements; it only allocates memory.

Comment: What is the actual question or the problem? Placement new constructs an object 'in-place' at the memory specified as the parameter. Nothing more. Your placement new constructor looks good. What I would add on the other hand is rvalue reference and std::forward the args. The comment on 'not constructing' the elements is wrong. It calls default constructors

Comment: @user2296177 that's not true, `new` will default construct every element.

Comment: @MarkRansom You are correct. I tested it out before commenting and got uninitialized values. I shouldn't have assumed.

Comment: @user2296177 there may be an exception in the case of a POD type. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8256293/default-initialization-of-pod-vs-non-pod-class-types

Answer (score 10):

> I read some stuff about the danger of using placement new over
>   operator new[] but couldn't figure out if the following is ok or not,
>   and if not, what's wrong with it [...]

For `operator new[]` vs. placement new, it's only really bad (as in typically-crashy type of undefined behavior) if you mix the two strategies together.

The main choice you typically have to make is to use one or the other. If you use `operator new[]`, then you construct all the elements for the entire capacity of the container in advance and overwrite them in methods like `push_back`. You don't destroy them on removal in methods like `erase`, just kind of keep them there and adjust the size, overwrite elements, and so forth. You both construct and allocate a multiple elements all in one go with `operator new[]`, and destroy and deallocate them all in one go using `operator delete[]`.

**Why Placement New is Used For Standard Containers**

First thing to understand if you want to start rolling your own vectors or other standard-compliant sequences (that aren't simply linked structures with one element per node) in a way that actually destroys elements when they are removed, constructs elements (not merely overwrite them) when added, is to separate the idea of allocating the memory for the container and constructing the elements for it in place. So quite to the contrary, in this case, placement new isn't bad. It's a fundamental necessity to achieve the general qualities of the standard containers. But we can't mix it with `operator new[]` and `operator delete[]` in this context.

For example, you might allocate the memory to hold 100 instances of T in `reserve`, but you don't want to default construct them as well. You want to construct them in methods like `push_back`, `insert`, `resize`, the `fill ctor`, `range ctor`, `copy ctor`, etc. -- methods that actually add *elements* and not merely the capacity to hold them. That's why we need *placement* new.

Otherwise we lose the generality of `std::vector` which avoids constructing elements that aren't there, can copy construct in `push_backs` rather than simply overwriting existing ones with `operator=`, etc.

So let's start with the constructor:

```
_data = new T[_capacity];
```

... this will invoke the default constructors for all the elements. We don't want that (neither the default ctor requirement nor this expense), as the whole point of using `placement new` is to construct elements in-place of allocated memory, and this would have already constructed all elements. Otherwise any use of placement new anywhere will try to construct an already-constructed element a second time, and will be UB.

Instead you want something like this:

```
_data = static_cast<T*>(malloc(_capacity * sizeof(T)));
```

This just gives us a raw chunk of bytes.

Second, for `push_back`, you're doing:

```
_data[_size++] = t;
```

That's trying to use the assignment operator, and, after our previous modification, on an uninitialized/invalid element which hasn't been constructed yet. So we want:

```
new(_data + _size) T(t);
++size;
```

... that makes it use the copy constructor. It makes it match up with what `push_back` is actually supposed to do: creating new elements in the sequence instead of simply overwriting existing ones.

Your erase method needs some work even at the basic logic level if you want to handle removals from the middle of the container. But just from the resource management standpoint, if you use placement new, you want to manually invoke destructors for removed elements. For example:

```
if (p == &back()) { --_size; return end(); }
```

... should be more like:

```
if (p == &back())
{
    --size;
    (_data + _size)->~T();
    return end(); 
}
```

Your `emplace_back` manually invokes a destructor but it shouldn't do this. `emplace_back` should only add, not remove (and destroy) existing elements. It should be quite similar to `push_back` but simply invoking the move ctor.

Your destructor does this:

```
~myVector() {
   delete[] _data;
}
```

But again, that's UB when we take this approach. We want something more like:

```
~myVector() {
   for (int j=0; j < _size; ++j)
      (_data + j)->~T();
   free(_data);
}
```

There's still a whole lot more to cover like exception-safety which is a whole different can of worms.

But this should get you started with respect to proper usage of placement new in a data structure against some memory allocator (`malloc/free` in this exemplary case).

Last but not least:

> (couldn't use stl for memory reasons)

... this might be an unusual reason. Your implementation doesn't necessarily use any less memory than a `vector` with `reserve` called in advance to give it the appropriate `capacity`. You might shave off a few bytes for on a per-container-level (not on a per-element level) with the choice of 32-bit integrals and no need to store an allocator, but it's going to be a very small memory savings in exchange for a boatload of work.

This kind of thing can be a useful learning exercise though to help you build some data structures outside the standard in a more standard-compliant way (ex: unrolled lists which I find quite useful).

I ended up having to reinvent some `vectors` and vector-like containers for ABI reasons (we wanted a container we could pass through our API that was guaranteed to have the same ABI regardless of what compiler was used to build a plugin). Even then, I would have much preferred simply using `std::vector`.

Note that if you just want to take control of how `vector` allocates memory, you can do that by specifying your own allocator with a compliant interface. This might be useful, for example, if you want a `vector` which allocates 128-bit aligned memory for use with aligned move instructions using SIMD.

Comment: +1 for the last comment. I would understand doing this for learning purposes but clearly he will end up with something far worse than std::vector looking at your approaches. Not worth the trouble I guess.

Comment: You can just do `new char[_capacity * sizeof(T)]`, no need for `malloc`.

Comment: @zenith Quite right, though typically if when we use placement new for some custom data structure, it often involves some low-level allocator which might just return void*, e.g. I thought it might more directly map to whatever the OP might want to do with these types of things.

Comment: You might also want to mention the `::operator new` allocation functions. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new

Comment: @user2296177 That's a nice idea, though I wasn't sure if what OP meant by "memory" reasons was to overload standard allocation behavior (in which case the interface of `std::allocator` might also be of interest) with a custom alloc or simply memory compactness, e.g. I up-voted your comment though in case that's of interest.

Comment: As for the last comment - what about if you want to use an std::map or a std::list in a shared memory segment?  The template allocator is used only for the value type and not for the pointers so it doesn't work.  That's the reason boost interprocess provides containers instead of just allocators.

Comment: Yeah, the way the standard lib works with allocators is quite annoying and limiting in many scenarios. But there's a few basic needs sometimes where specifying a custom allocator for a standard container can serve the need.

Comment: @zenith `malloc` returns maximally-aligned memory; `new char[...]` does not.  I suspect the answer is `new aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T),alignof(T)>[N]`.

Comment: @Ike, Thanks for the effort and long answer, but this was not meant to be a code review (it's not even the real code), and you did not answer my question - Was there any "memory violation" here? I don't know who's "we" in "we don't want that", you altered my constructor without explaining why and then it forced altering all the rest. I understand how altering the ctor like you did induce the other changes, but I **do** want it like that.

Comment: The use of operator= is for backward compatibility, and as for using std::vector - I can't afford anyone using it forgetting to use reserve and overallocating / reallocating memory. As for alignment issues, I have to admit I wasn't aware of that. Does `new T[n]` return an aligned memory? As for move operators, std::forward, etc. - these are things I'm not familiar with yet, but frankly I don't think I need them for my purposes, and I don't want to dive in yet unless it's really necessary cause as you said, it's quite annoying and I might add ugly and too complex.

Comment: I'd like to keep it simple as possible, even if not super-general and covers cases I would never encounter, and I only want to know if I'm doing something which is essentially wrong.

Comment: As an aside, the "we" in "we don't want that" is a [nosism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nosism). It is basically referring to the author.

Comment: Added an answer explaining exactly why the ctor was incompatible with any use of placement new, and also why `std::vector` and the like avoid using `operator new[]` there.

Comment: I agree about it being better, but I had to do so to support what others have wrote and used before me. I have no intention in being stl compatible, but rather compatible with existing bad design.. the old, widespread, vector (which uses malloc and free, but not placement new) does not allow copy constructor for itself, but rather only operator= (I know it could in principal be explicit instead) and thus to hold elements which hold the old vector in them, I had to not require T::T(T const&) which would require T to define one, but rather T::operator=(T const&) which would be defaultly defined.

Comment: Basically if you do want to use placement new and have methods like push_back use copy ctor instead of assignment operator, have methods like erase actually destroy elements and not just keep them in the container, etc, it basically boils down to using placement new and manual invocations of dtors -- which may or may not be what you want. Apologies -- maybe the way I described things was a bit nosy, but I meant, "This is what we want assuming you want something similar to the standard containers (which use placement new)."

Comment: Now about using `new T[n]`, that's perfectly safe from an alignment perspective. It'll align appropriately based on what `T` is. Where it gets different is if we *do* use placement new, then `new T[n]` would construct `n` elements. So when we avoid that, we need to use an allocator which does maximally align like `malloc` or start involving things like `aligned_storage_t` to ensure proper alignment for `T`.

Comment: I now see that you deleted the only answer you gave to my very question =) so thanks, All my intention was to understand why new[] then new() then delete[] is wrong, because someone said it somewhere on the internet, but if you say it's good, I take your word for it.. about the "good practice tips" you mainly addressed, again, I agree, but I don't have this degree of freedom.. Thanks..

Comment: @elad Oh sorry, I deleted a couple of comments here but only because I incorporated them into the answer (didn't want to spam this thread too much -- you can find them there). About the question though, what was it exactly? I had a hard time deducing exactly what it was, since the title of the question is related to placement new in a home-made vector (so that's mainly what I wrote about -- how to write a home-made container using it).

Comment: @elad Oh, I think the main thing that looks like a question is whether `placement new` is bad (that's in the updated answer), and why here it's actually needed typically to implement these containers (at least in a way that avoids overwriting and not destroying elements at the time they are added/removed).

Comment: The main way to look at it though is not the `operator=` requirement. That's not the most trippy part, typically (it's not the biggest deal to provide operator=). The main thing to ask is, "If I erase elements from my container, should they be destroyed or not?" Typically the answer is yes, or else calling methods like erase will never destroy anything until you destroy the entire container or call `clear` or something like that. That's where we need placement new the most -- not just to avoid copy assignment and overwriting stuff but actually making sure they get destroyed at the right time.

Comment: @Ike, to clarify, the question was if it's a real danger (memory-leak level) to use placement new over a memory allocated (and empty-constructed) using new T[n], and/or using a plain delete[] afterwards. The code is of relevance, but is here just to give the context. I was and am aware of it being less than best practice, so unless the design is of real danger itself, it's irrelevant here (though your answer can surely help me and others learn about the good way).

Comment: @elad I see -- for `operator new[]` vs. placement new, it's only really bad (as in crashy, undefined behavior) if you *mix* the two strategies together. The main choice you have to make it use one or the other. If you use `operator new[]`, then you construct all the elements for the entire capacity of the container in advance and overwrite them. You don't destroy them on removal, just kind of keep them there and adjust the size, overwrite elements, and so forth.

Comment: @elad So yes, given what you've been telling me, maybe what's appropriate is to avoid placement new outright. You either have to commit to the idea that allocating memory for the container and constructing/destroying elements are two separate and decoupled processes, or couple them together and avoid placement new and manual destructor calls outright in favor of just `operator new[]` and `operator delete[]`.

Comment: @Ike, forgot to mention (but it's in the code), anytime I use placement-new, I destruct the old element first. **is it still a serious problem?** also, I'm ok with destructing the elements only when necessary or at the end of the run. It's not a real danger if you don't do wierd stuff with the vector, and that I can assume.

Comment: @Ike, one thing I didn't understand is your saying : _Where it gets different is if we do use placement new, then new T[n] would construct n elements_. can you clarify? is this what I'm doing? thanks

Comment: @elad I added a couple paragraphs at the top of the answer about the difference. Apologies to keep pointing you to updated answers.

Comment: @elad `"I destruct the old element first."` Where this gets trippy I think was how you were mixing `operator new[]` and placement new together. In that case, technically speaking, you do have to destroy the existing element (which was constructed by `operator new[]`) prior to constructing it in place with placement new. But generally we shouldn't be mixing these two strategies -- normally if you use placement new, there should be no element constructed for the memory in which you construct an element in-place.

Comment: @elad I would very, very strongly recommend (as in, even if you can avoid glitches, the code would be like a stack of cards), that if you use `operator new[]` and `operator delete[]` here, to avoid using placement new and manual destructor calls. It's just a little too hairy to mix the two together -- since those operators want to allocate/deallocate and construct/destroy many elements for you in bulk, and we're kind of digging in and manually taking partial control (but without the full control we'd typically need to do this properly).

Comment: @ike, Thanks, I read the edit, but you keep using phrases like _we want_ or _we don't want_, so again, please do not assume I want to avoid extra constructions or lacking destruction, or aspire to a general design. I just don't want memory leaks or undefined behaviour... is my code the way it is going to cause such a thing to happen? A clarification about the alignment (I asked 2 comments above) would also be nice..

Comment: @elad In that case, let's start with forgetting placement new and manual destructor calls -- which is what we should do if you do not want these things. In that case, simply use `operator new[]/delete[]` to handle the construction and destruction. Use `operator=` to overwrite elements in place (instead of constructing/destroying in place), and you should be set. We avoid the gotchas with mixing these two techniques provided we do not mix.

Comment: @elad About alignment, `new T[n]` ensures proper alignment for elements of type `T`. But of course, if we use `new char[n]` to allocate memory for `Foos`, we can be in danger of improper alignment. That's where `aligned_storage_t` can come in handy.

Comment: @Ike, my reason for doing it is the assumption that T::T() is very fast, and T::operator= is very slow, which is the case e.g for classes that hold containers themselves. I don't want to construct the new element outside and then pass it through asignment, and that's why I introduced the "emplace_back" function. I know that doing a move-like-asignment should probably cover that, but I'm still not familiar enough with move and r-value references, plus, I cannot always alter the objects I deal with, so I'm doing the best I can given them as they are.

Comment: anyway, I ran some tests and I understand that my code is fine by the standards of the question. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @elad Yes, that speed issue you cited in addition to generality (not *requiring* T to provide `operator=`) is precisely why the standard authors use placement new. But you lose the speed advantage if you use `operator new[]`, because then you have to not only copy construct, but *destroy* the already-constructed element created by `operator new[]`. It's generally slower to destroy an element and then create a new one than merely overwrite it. If you use the placement new strategy in the answer though, you can avoid the redundant construction/destruction, and construct elements in place.

Comment: @elad If you are really interested in avoiding `operator=` and all that, I can construct you a minimal example of something simple (ex: a stack) which uses placement new for pushes and manual calls to the destructor for pops as part of the answer. Would that be helpful? I can make it very simple.

Comment: @Ike, thanks, but I know how to do it (except && / move, special alignment, etc.). My situation is that I have to have operator= for push_back (meaning it will be required from T, rather than CopyCtor), but wanted to extend the freedom for T's which do have and "want" it. If you're so eagger to post this example, be my guest, I'm sure others could benefit from it, but I doubt I'll learn something `new =)` (again, as long as you keep it basic and simple). You're also welcome to surprise me..

Comment: @elad I'm really reluctant but, I *suppose* if you are careful, you can call the destrutor and then copy construct the element in place with `operator new(mem)` as a means of overwriting in spite of using `operator new[]`. It's a very unusual thing and trading off the need to overwrite with `operator=` with the need to redundantly destroy an existing element and construct a new one, but if your precise needs compel you down that route, it might be doable.

Comment: @elad One thing I recommend if you develop these containers is make a test against a user-defined type, like myVector<Foo>. And make Foo increment a static/global counter each time it is constructed (copy constructed/default constructed) and decrement it when it is destroyed... and make sure in your test that doing a bunch of stuff with `myVector` and then destroying it leads to an instance count of 0, not negative/positive.. since that's the trippy part -- making sure the constructor calls and destructor calls are symmetrical, especially if you mix `operator new[]` and placement new.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96171/discussion-on-answer-by-ike-c-placement-new-in-a-home-made-vector-container).