# How to make an array that holds unique_ptrs?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++14, unique-ptr

I am under the assumption that the code bellow is a unique_ptr to an array (aka not what I want)

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> arr;
arr = std::make_unique<int[]> (5);
arr[0] = *new int(1);
delete &arr[0]; // malloc error, want to avoid "delete"
```

However, I want an array that holds unique_ptrs like so...

```
std::unique_ptr<int> arr2 [];       //Error, requires explicit size
arr2 = std::make_unique<int> [5];   //Desirable, does not compile
arr2[0] = std::make_unique<int>(1); //Desirable, does not compile
```

How do I go about making an array of unique_ptrs? If that is not possible, then how do I deal with a malloc error?

Comment: 2 easy options: `std::array<std::unique_ptr<int>, 5>`, `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>`

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to accomplish?  Do you really need an array of `unique_ptr`s?

Comment: @NathanOliver, supposedly, yes. What's so strange about it?

Comment: @SergeyA Nothing strange but I'm wondering if the op even needs this.  I hate giving people an answer to X when they really need to ask Y instead.

Comment: I am trying to make my own vector. Also why use shared pointers? Array would not be pointer to the same objects.

Comment: @Anton If you are writing your own vector class, why would you need an array of unique pointers, as opposed to a unique_ptr to an array?

Comment: Thank you SergeyA, I do not want a unique ptr array because each element requires a new and delete.

Comment: @SergeyA You would think that but as you can see from the OP's comment that isn't what they need.  They just need `std::unique_ptr<Type[]>` or a buffer and placement new.  An array of `unique_ptr`'s is not needed to build a vector.

Comment: `delete &arr[0];` is trying to delete the wrong thing. Rather than delete the `new`ed `int` it's trying to delete the array. The array is owned by the `unique_ptr` and doesn't need `delete`ing and the `new`ed `int` has already been leaked. Do you want instead `arr[0] = 1;`?

Comment: @NathanOliver, yes, you were right. Can I borrow your crystal ball for the next NY Lottery jackpot?

Comment: @SergeyA Sure.  You have to split the winnings though.

Comment: user4581301, using arr[0] = new int(0), because I eventually want to expand this to generics, and so I was creating an int object, because you woud do something like this with generics arr[0] = *new T(stuff)

Comment: @Anton I think you might be interested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906008/c-placement-new-in-a-home-made-vector-container)

Comment: In that case you need an array of  pointers to `int`, not an array of `int`. Do not force a pointer at this stage. When you carry through to generalizing your vector with a template, leave it up to the user to specialize the template with a pointer.

Comment: @NathanOliver, that helps (to a degree), thanks. However I would still rather stick with unique_ptrs, because other parts of my program will use unique_ptrs. Additionally, I am curious, because I have not seen an array that manages unique_ptrs in google.

Comment: @user4581301 , yes I want an array of pointers to int. Which is why I am trying to make an array of unique_ptrs.

Comment: It's a perfectly good question, people. Another good question is why there is so much needless toxicity in the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> arr;
arr = std::make_unique<int[]> (5);
```

At this point you have a `unique_ptr` to an array of `int`. This sounds like it is exactly what you want.

```
arr[0] = *new int(1);
```

But this is questionable. It dynamically allocates a single `int`, assigns 1 to the allocated `int`, then it assigns the value, 1, at the allocated `int` into the array at element 0. the allocated `int` is left hanging with nothing pointing at it, and is now exceptionally difficult to `delete. This is a memory leak.

```
delete &arr[0]; // malloc error, want to avoid "delete"
```

And as you've seen, this is fatal. Rather than attempting to `delete` the leaked `int`, `delete` has been invoked with a pointer to the array stored in the `unique_ptr`. Eventually the unique_ptr`will try to`delete` the array and fail because it's already gone.

Based on comments, OP intends

```
std::unique_ptr<int*[]> arr;
arr = std::make_unique<int*[]> (5);
arr[0] = new int(1);
delete arr[0];
```

But I'd like to talk them out of this idea. Let's look at their end goal: a templated class

```
template <class TYPE>
class MyVector
{
    std::unique_ptr<TYPE[]> arr; // array of whatever type
public:
    MyVector(size_t size): arr(std::make_unique<TYPE[]> (size))
    {

    }
    TYPE& operator[](size_t index)
    {
        return arr[index];
    }
    // note the complete lack of growing, shrinking and other vector goodness
    // as they are not needed for this example.
};
```

We can use this class with just about anything.

```
int main()
{
    // vector of int
    MyVector<int> vec(5);
    vec[0] = 1;

    // vector of pointer to int (yuck)
    MyVector<int*> vec2(5);
    vec2[0] = new int(1);
    delete vec2[0];

    // vector of smart pointer to int (also yuck, but less yuck)
    MyVector<std::unique_ptr<int>> vec3(5);
    vec3[0] = std::make_unique<int>(1);

    // vector of std::string
    MyVector<std::string> vec4(5);
    vec4[0] = "I am the very model of a modern major general...";
}
```

If the user of the vector want it to contain pointers, they can say so. There is no reason to force the user to use a pointer.

Answer (score 4):

Do you want an array that holds `unique_ptr`s (as in the title), or a `unique_ptr` holding an array (as in your examples)?

---

If an array of `unique_ptr`s is what you want, then

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>
```

or

```
std::array<std::unique_ptr<int>, 3>;
```

(for example) will do the job.

---

If a `unique_ptr` holding an array is what you're after, then `unique_ptr<int[]>` will work (there is a [partial specialisation of `unique_ptr` to support it](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)), although you can't use `std::make_unique` and will need to call `operator new[]` yourself:

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> p{new int[42]};
```

However, if you think you need this, what you most likely really want is `std::vector`, and I'd strongly recommend using that instead.

Comment: Yes, just like the title suggests, what about the basic array, (instead of std::array)? Is that doable? Also I did say "However, I want an array that holds unique_ptrs". Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: use vectors. They are much easier to work with and you don't have to explicidly allocate memory. You should also use typedefs for syntax simplicity.

```
typedef unique_ptr<int> intPtr;
vector<intPtr> vec;
vec.push_back(make_unique<int>(69));

auto myIntPtr = make_unique<int>(16);
vec.push_back(move(myIntPtr)); // unique ptrs cannot be copied, must be moved

unique_ptr<int[5]> p1; // valid syntax
```

Comment: I am trying to make a vector, and so using vectors to make a vector seems redundant. While its my fault for not making this apparent, I did say I was trying to make an array of unique_ptrs (which is different from unique_ptr to array).