# default initialization, value initialization and in-class-initialization of object not getting properly?

Tags: c++, list-initialization, value-initialization, in-class-initialization, default-initialization

You might feel code is long and I write lot of things but believe me it is quite simple.

I referred these two answers on stack-overflow for understanding this.
[post1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3803288/11862989) & [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8106064/11862989)

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>

class A
        {
        public:
            int k1=3;
            float f1=34.20;
            char ch1='a';
            std::string str1="bonaparte";

            void display()
            {
                std::cout<<k1<<" "<<f1<<" "<<ch1<<" "<<str1<<" xx\n";
            }

        };

class B
{
    public:
        int k2;
        float f2;
        char ch2;
        std::string str2;

        void display()
        {
            std::cout<<k2<<" "<<f2<<" "<<ch2<<" "<<str2<<" xx\n";
        }

};

A a1;
B b1;

A *p1=new A;
B *q1=new B;
int main()
{
    A a2, a3{};
    B b2, b3{};

    A *p2=new A;
    A *p3=new A{};
    A *p4=new A();

    B *q2=new B;
    B *q3=new B{};
    B *q4=new B();

    a1.display();
    a2.display();
    a3.display();
    p1->display();
    p2->display();
    p3->display();
    p4->display();

    std::cout<<"\n\n";

    b1.display();
    b2.display();
    b3.display();
    q1->display();
    q2->display();
    q3->display();
    q4->display();


}
```

**Output**

```
3 34.2 a bonaparte xx
3 34.2 a bonaparte xx
3 34.2 a bonaparte xx
3 34.2 a bonaparte xx
3 34.2 a bonaparte xx
3 34.2 a bonaparte xx
3 34.2 a bonaparte xx


0 0    xx
13965136 0 ╠  xx
0 0    xx
38872208 0 p  xx
38872208 0 p  xx
0 0    xx
0 0    xx
```

**Class B**

`b1` is value initialized precisely zero initialized.

`b2` is default initialized means no initialized.

`b3` is brace initialized means value initialized which leads to zero initialized.

I am not able to create `b4()` like `q4` (not exact like but you know what I mean) as it leads function definition rather than declaration of object( Most vexing parse)

I think `q1` should value initialized but after seeing output it's not matches what I think.

`q2` is default initialized means no initialized.

`q3` is brace initialized means value initialized which leads to zero initialized.

`q4` calls constructor but there is no user defined constructor so it should default initialized means no initialized.

I know `q1`, `q2`, `q3`, `q4` are pointer but just to easy I am using above language for ex. `q3` is brace initialized. but I think you know what I mean.

What I believe regarding `b1`, `b2`, `b3` turns out to be true so I don't have any question regarding that might  be it is just mere coincidence so correct me if I am wrong.

Regarding `q1`, `q2`, `q3`, `q4`

what I assume for `b1` I think it should work for `q1` too but it not happens so please explain that.

Regarding `q2` what I think matches so no problem but still correct me if I am wrong.

Now there is confusion with `q3` & `q4`. I think both are calling for constructors but I am not sure. I assume both calling constructor but we have not user defined constructors so it should default initialized means un-initialized isn't that right ? so how come both are value initialized precisely zero initialized.

**Class A**

So if we do in-class initialization no matter where we declare object it's going to initialize with what we provide, I feel it's right but just want to confirm and please add if you would like to tell me bit more about this.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/qKnGx6W4f only `b2.display()` shows uninitialized members

Comment: _"if we do in-class initialization no matter where we declare object it's going to initialize with what we provide"_ It's generally not true. You can "override" this initialization in custom-defined constructors. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/779Tc5Pc7.

Comment: `q3` and `q4` are both [_value-initialized_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization). In case of `B`, default-initialization results in _zero-initialization_.

Comment: @DanielLangr so why is global `b1` and  `q2` end up zero-initialized, though `b2` - not?

Comment: AFAIK, objects with static storage duration are _zero-initialized_, which is the case of `b1`. As for `*q2`, its `k2`, `f2` and `ch2` have undetermined values. Which may or may not be 0.

Comment: `This question needs debugging details. It is not currently accepting answers.` it seems like the question has been closed for an invalid reason

Comment: Note that this question (plus your comments) asks many questions at once. You should better ask only a single question per question. With the minimal code; the code here is very long for a single question.

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik first of all thanks. regarding your 2nd comment  `only b2.display() shows uninitialized members`.  what's about `q1` & `q2` I think both are un-initialized aren't they ?

Comment: @DanielLangr Thanks I got your first comment but I think your 2nd and 3rd comment are contradictory to each other.

Comment: @DanielLangr Regarding your last comment I know it's too much stuff at once but I also don't want to  ask such that but to get understand difference among all these initialization types I have to ask that's why ? if you feel I am right please reopen.

Comment: @AbhishekMane godbolt shows otherwise. Look at the link in the first comment

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik yes I checked link but how come it is possible different outputs for your compiler even I am using `CLion` IDE with migw64 version 8.1 for C++23 still same output which I showed in Question

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik please reply.

Comment: @AbhishekMane It's a bit more complicated. `B` has an implicitly-defined default constructor which is _non-trivial_ due the the non-trivial default constructor of `B` subobject of type `std::string`. This default constructor of `B` does not initialize members `k1`, `f1`, and `ch1`. In `B *q1=new B;`, `B b2;`, and `B *q2=new B;`, only this constructor is used and those members, therefore, have unspecified values in all mentioned cases. Note that unspecified may be zeros as well.

Comment: @AbhishekMane However, if you write `B b3{};`, `B *q3=new B{}`, and `B *q4=new B();`, then so-called _zero-initialization_ is performed first, since the default constructor of `B` is neither custom-defined nor deleted. This zeros-out the members `k1`, `f1`, and `ch1`. Then, the default constructor is called since it is non-trivial (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization). With `B b1;`, the situation is effectively the same since it is a variable with _static storage duration_. (BTW, I voted for reopen.)

Comment: @AbhishekMane Also note that reading _indetermined (unspecified) values_ results in _undefined behavior_ with only few exceptions (`unsigned char` or `std::byte`), which do not apply here. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization. Your program, therefore, does not have defined behavior.

Comment: You can see the difference here where with _value-initialization_, the `int` member is additionally zeroed: https://godbolt.org/z/f6Maed8j7. With _default-initialization_, it is not.

Comment: @AbhishekMane I think it deserves a question of its own

Comment: @DanielLangr https://godbolt.org/z/sWa1z4K4j see here I removed `std::string` from `class B` still `b2` is giving unspecified value ? and in my `CLion` ide with mingw64 all `b2`, `q1`, `q2` are unspecified. So how come you are telling that default initialization results in zero initialization in case of `class B`. Also please note by mistaken in your first comment in todays reply you talked about class B and used `k1`, `f1`... instead of `k2`, `f2` ...

Comment: @DanielLangr also what happen if class (`x`) contain object of another class(`y`) which has user-defined constructor. So assume former class(`x`) has no user provided constructor so what's it causes to default initialize all the members of class(`x`) can you tell bit about that

Comment: @AbhishekMane You are asking about many different cases. Effects of all types of initialization are in detail described in the documentation. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization, and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization. There, it is specified what happens in each of the cases you are interested in.

Comment: @DanielLangr okay I will check