# value initialization for automatic variables

Tags: c++, value-initialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [non-copyable objects and value initialization: g++ vs msvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671532/non-copyable-objects-and-value-initialization-g-vs-msvc)
>   [Value-initializing an automatic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298001/value-initializing-an-automatic-object)

Consider the following statement:

> It's not really possible to value-initialize an automatic object.

Is this statement true?  I see no problem in doing this:

```
int main()
{
    int i = int();
}
```

Comment: Your `i` is copy-initialized, not value-initialized. Only the temporary is value-initialized.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Value-initializing an automatic object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298001/value-initializing-an-automatic-object) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671532/non-copyable-objects-and-value-initialization-g-vs-msvc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term `value-initialization` is defined in 8.5 [dcl.init] paragraph 16, 4th bullet:

> If the initializer is (), the object is value-initialized.

That is, value-initialization of an automatic variable would look like this:

```
int i();
```

However, this is a declaration of a function called `i` returning an `int`. Thus, it is impossible to value-initialize an automatic. In your example, the temporary is value-initialized and the automatic variable is copy-initialized. You can verify that this indeed requires the copy constructor to be accessible using a test class which doesn't have an accessible copy constructor:

```
class noncopyable {
    noncopyable(noncopyable const&);
public:
    noncopyable();
};

int main() {
    noncopyable i = noncopyable(); // ERROR: not copyable
}
```

---

**SINCE C++11**: `int i{};` does the [job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6298050/10750537) (see also [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization)).

Comment: :is int i(6) a value initialization and what will int i(int()) means

Comment: why this is value initialization??
T * p2 = new T();

Comment: The form `int i(6)` is _direct-initialization_ (8.5 [dcl.init] paragraph 15). `int i(int())` declares a function named `i` returning an `int` and taking a function with no arguments and returning `int` as argument. In `T* p2 = new T()` the `new`ed object is value-initialized, the pointer `p2` is copy initialized.