# Miscellaneous temporary object T()

Tags: c++, most-vexing-parse, temporary-objects

Consider this code :

```
int main()
{
    int i(6); //this will result in i==6,but consider next initializations

    int j(int()); 

    T * p2 = new T(); 
}
```

I find that the value of `j` is 1, but this should be 0 because `int()` is a temporary with value equal to 0.

Also, the syntax for the `new` operator is `new typename`, but here `T()` will be a temporary object instead of a type name.

Comment: You're confused, `new T()` does dynamically allocate a `T` object and value initialize it, it does not create a temporary.  What are you actually trying to do.

Comment: This should be closed, right now there's no question, and if a question is added, it'll be a dupe of either the links in Nawaz's answer or else http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671532/non-copyable-objects-and-value-initialization-g-vs-msvc and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298001/value-initializing-an-automatic-object

Comment: In fact, TJ just asked one of those questions two hours ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346687/value-initialization-for-automatic-variables  **Next time read the question links left in the comments, TJ!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int j(int());
```

This doesn't declare an object. Instead it declares a function which takes a function as argument, and returns `int`. The type of the function which it takes as argument is this :

```
 typedef int (*funtype)();
```

That, is, a function which returns `int`, and takes nothing as argument.

The parsing of such a declaration is commonly known as:

- [Most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)
- [Most vexing parse: why doesn't A a(()); work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work)

---

And in the `new` syntax, `T()` doesn't create a temporary object. That is not how it is to be seen. Instead, you've to look at the entire expression `new T()` which first allocates memory for an object of type `T`, and then construct the object in that memory. If `T` is a user-defined type, then it calls the default constructor to construct the object, after allocating the memory.

Comment: And the fix is to either use extra parenthesis to make it an invalid function declaration: `int j((int()));`, or avoid the syntax: `int j = int();`.

Comment: @nawaz: and what about secoond question

Answer (score 1):

> Also syntax for new operator is typename *variable_name = new typename, but here `T()` will be a temporary object but not type name.

Similarly to the Most Vexing Parse, `T()` has different meanings depending on context. It does not always produce a temporary, but generally initializes some new anonymous object or subobject. The object might be

- a temporary if `T()` is in an expression,
- base subobject if `T()` appears before the body in a constructor, or
- the referent of the pointer if `T()` appears after `new`. Note that the *pointer* has a name, but the object is anonymous.

`new T` and `new T()` do slightly different things: for some types, `new T` leaves values uninitialized. (The official term is *default-initialization*.) There is no corresponding grammatical construct for base subobjects or temporaries: base subobjects are default-initialized by omitting the initializer, and temporaries are not allowed to be default-initialized. The difference is minor, since in all these cases a constructor *will* be called if you defined one, and a constructor should always be defined, and it should always initialize all members. Exceptions are fundamental types such as `int` and simple structures like `std::array<char, 1000>`.

To be on the safe side, it's best to avoid `new T` in favor of `new T()` just to make sure that things are nicely zeroed out in the absence of a constructor.